# How can I get rid of the zombie topic I've just created?

Tags: support, bug, documentation

There was a topic with a single example in a tag on documentation.

I moved it to another topic. The move dialogue told me that this is going to delete the then empty topic.

My edit got approved, the example got moved, but the empty topic is still there in the topic list.

Clicking it gives me the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"-page. 
Sometimes that guy on the picture is wearing a different shirt.
Will this topic linger on in the topic list forever? What if that guy is running out of shirts? How can I get rid of the topic? Or is that actually a vampire topic, that gets fried by the scheduled morning sun aka some automated update/deletion process?

**update**

The topic is gone now. What I think happened is that it still had some overlooked text in the remarks section. Can a non-example section keep the topic alive if all examples are gone? Did this prevent the topic from being deleted automatically?

Comment: I've heard that Plants work quite well to get rid of Zombies ...

Comment: +1 for "What if that guy is running out of shirts?"